# Erro de 5% na URI (em linguagem C)

Tags: c, uri

O código dá erro em casos como  576.73 ou 576.43, no campo das moedas de 0.01 os demais campo respondem corretamente. Não sei exatamente a razão de retornar 2 moedas de 0.01 nos casos acima, mas quando o input é 0.03, 0.04 ou 0.06 entre outras tentativas retiradas do site uDebug o resultado fica correto.

A descrição do problema é:

Leia um valor de ponto flutuante com duas casas decimais. Este valor representa um valor monetário. A seguir, calcule o menor número de notas e moedas possíveis no qual o valor pode ser decomposto. As notas consideradas são de 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2. As moedas possíveis são de 1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05 e 0.01. A seguir mostre a relação de notas necessárias.
Entrada

O arquivo de entrada contém um valor de ponto flutuante N (0 ≤ N ≤ 1000000.00).
Saída

Imprima a quantidade mínima de notas e moedas necessárias para trocar o valor inicial, conforme exemplo fornecido.

Obs: Utilize ponto (.) para separar a parte decimal.

Saida esperada para entrada 576.73

```
NOTAS:
5 nota(s) de R$ 100.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 50.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 20.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 5.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
1 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
2 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
3 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01
```

Meu código em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
float valor;
int div;

scanf("%f", &valor);
///// NOTAS
printf("NOTAS:\n");
div = (valor/100);
valor = valor - (div*100);
printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 100.00\n", div);
div = (valor/50);
valor = valor - (div*50);
printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 50.00\n", div);
div = (valor/20);
valor = valor - (div*20);
printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 20.00\n", div);
div = (valor/10);
valor = valor - (div*10);
printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 10.00\n", div);
div = (valor/5);
valor = valor - (div*5);
printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 5.00\n", div);
div = (valor/2);
valor = valor - (div*2);
printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 2.00\n", div);
///// MOEDAS
printf("MOEDAS:\n");
valor *= 100;
div = (valor/100);
valor = valor - (div*100);
printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 1.00\n", div);
div = (valor/50);
valor = valor - (div*50);
printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.50\n", div);
div = (valor/25);
valor = valor - (div*25);
printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.25\n", div);
div = (valor/10);
valor = valor - (div*10);
printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.10\n", div);
div = (valor/5);
valor = valor - (div*5);
printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.05\n", div);
div = valor / 1;
printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.01\n", div);

return 0;
}
```

Minha saída (para input: 576.73)

```
NOTAS:
5 nota(s) de R$ 100.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 50.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 20.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 5.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
1 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
2 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
2 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01
```

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Tente utilizar o valor `double` ao invés de `float`.

Comment: Funcionou, vlw mesmo Danizavtz.

Comment: Cara, eu não sei os termos de busca, mas está relacionado com representação de números binários em ponto flutuante (padrão IEEE754 para aritmética em pontos flutuantes), dizima periódica em binários e acumulo de erros em multiplicação e divisão, quando utilizando ponto flutuantes.

Comment: Para evitar a falta de precisão nas representações float/double você pode multiplicar os valores por 100 e trabalhar com inteiros e utilizar o operador resto da divisão (%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O limite para o dinheiro no enunciado é um milhão então cabe em um `int`. Mais importante, cem milhões cabem num `int`. Então multiplique os valores todos por 100 e use `int` e tudo fica certinho.

Não use `float` ou mesmo `double` para tratar dinheiro ou vai mais cedo --- tipo agora --- ou mais tarde ter erros de arredondamento porque a representação de `float` não é exata.

Por essa razão `COBOL` sempre foi a linguagem do dinheiro e dos relatórios financeiros: aritmética com dinheiro sem erros de arredondamento, usando `BCD`, dois dígitos decimais por byte.